# save vector into matrix/data frame value

Tags: r, vector, matrix

Is there a way, in R, to save a whole vector into one value of a matrix or data frame, without having to combine it into a single value first?

For example, if I had a vector..

```
pk<-c(0.021477,0.021114,0.022794,0.014858,0.009690,0.003255,0.002715)
```

and a matrix..

```
tst<-matrix(data=NA,nrow=4,ncol=4)
```

is there anyway of saying, for example..

```
tst[1,1]<-pk
```

?

I know I could paste the vector together, but I'm wondering whether there's a way of avoiding this? It's a matter of efficiency as the actual matrix is 33427 x 33427, with each vector ~ 300 values long, and I need to run further analysis on each value in the matrix. I'm hoping to find a way to speed up the analysis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can certainly put a vector in each element of a matrix. Try something like

```
tst<-matrix(data=list(),nrow=4,ncol=4)
tst[[1,1]] <- pk #note double square brackets needed for assignment
```

It doesn't print 'nicely'

```
tst
     [,1]      [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] Integer,5 NULL NULL NULL
[2,] NULL      NULL NULL NULL
[3,] NULL      NULL NULL NULL
[4,] NULL      NULL NULL NULL
```

but elements can be extracted in the obvious ways

```
> tst[1,1]
[[1]]
[1] 0.021477 0.021114 0.022794 0.014858 0.009690 0.003255 0.002715
#note list

> tst[[1,1]]
[1] 0.021477 0.021114 0.022794 0.014858 0.009690 0.003255 0.002715
#original vector
```

Answer (score 2):

If the vectors are of varying length, I can see two ways of dealing with it.  Either round up the lengths to the max and put things in an array

```
tst<- array(data=NA, dim=c(4,4,maxLen))
tst[1,1,1:length(pk)] <- pk
```

Alternatively you can just create a list of the `pk`s, and generate a map to translate the 1 dimensional list index with the 2D matrix element they would've corresponded to.

Which of these is optimal will depend on the downstream analysis you wish to do.  If there's 'inter-pk' communication (e.g. you use element 1 of the pk at [1,1] and element 1 of pk at [1,2], [2,1]...) then the array solution might be better.  But if all computations are within an individual vector, the list may be a better way to go

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the "as is" `I` function and make `pk` a 1 element list (that holds the vector):

```
pk <- c(0.021477,0.021114,0.022794,0.014858,0.009690,0.003255,0.002715)
dat <- data.frame(a <- I(list(pk)))
str(dat)
## 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  1 variable:
##  $ a....I.list.pk..:List of 1
##   ..$ : num  0.02148 0.02111 0.02279 0.01486 0.00969 ...
##   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "AsIs"

dat[1,1]
## [[1]]
## [1] 0.021477 0.021114 0.022794 0.014858 0.009690 0.003255 0.002715
```